# python loop through number of rows at a time

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops

Im trying to loop through a number of N rows at a time in a text file . How do I loop through the whole file for instance say it has 100 rows and print 10 at a time.
This is how far I got.

```
 N=10
 f=open("data.txt")
 for i in range(N):
     line=f.next().strip()
     print line
 f.close()
```

Comment: could you provide an input/output example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: What is the difference in "printing 10 at a time" and just printing each line?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could treat the file as an iterator and just take extra items from it on each iteration:

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        lines = [line] + [next(f) for _ in xrange(9)]  # have 1 already, so need 9
        # process lines
```

If your file length is not divisible by your chunk size, you can use `next(f, None)` instead, and filter out the `None`s before processing `lines`.

Comment: This will raise a `StopIteration` error (at least in Python 3) if the line count is not divisible by the step...

Comment: @brianpck You can use `next(f, None)` in that case. I updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @BKCapri - to remove the newlines: `lines = [line.strip() for line in lines]`

Comment: @arshajii - Perhaps `lines = [line] + list(iterator.islice(f, 0, 9))`. That might solve the not-evenly-divisible problem.